# How should dependency injection handle transitive dependencies?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

I'm thinking about how to structure some code in Scala that has traits depending on other traits, and I'm wondering whether dependency injection with self-typing is the best approach for this.

In the example code below, the `Adder` trait references functionality from the `HasLogger` trait through self-typing. The class `Doubler` extends `Adder` and hence also requires `HasLogger`. The class `Foo` also requires `HasLogger` for `Adder`, but also uses it directly.

If we were to modify one of the classes so that it no longer used `Adder`, how would we know whether we could also remove `HasLogger`? (In this case it is easy to check, but with many dependencies it would not be obvious). Also if there were many classes similar to `Doubler`, there would be repeated code as each would need to extend both `HasLogger` and `Adder`. Is this a situation where `Adder` should extend `HasLogger` instead of using self-typing?

```
trait HasLogger {
  val logger: Logger = new Logger

  class Logger {
    def log(msg: String): Unit = println(msg)
  }
}

trait Adder {
  this: HasLogger =>
  def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
    logger.log(s"Adding $x and $y")
    x + y
  }
}

class Doubler extends HasLogger with Adder {
  def double(x: Int): Int = add(x, x)
}

class Foo extends HasLogger with Adder {
  def logInt(x: Int): Unit = logger.log(x.toString)

  def add3(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int): Int = add(add(x, y), z)
}
```

Comment: That is known as the **cake pattern** and is famous for being horrible to maintain. The best way to handle dependencies is to pass them to constructors.

Comment: Can you explain how that would work in this situation? What are the advantages when compared with the cake pattern?

Comment: [Why cake pattern is bad](https://kubuszok.com/2018/cake-antipattern/) - [DI in Scala](https://di-in-scala.github.io/) I hope those two links provide you with enough information to answer your question by yourself. - Anyways, the TL;DR; would be, create a trait **Logger** with just one method `def log(msg: String): Unit`  and one implementation that prints to the stdout. Then you create another trait **Adder** which only provides the `def add(x: Int, y: Int): Int` methods, and create an implementation that receives a logger in its constructor.